# Using import_() function from pysvn package

Tags: python, svn, pysvn

I would like to know how to use the function import_() from pysvn package but I do not understand exactly all the different parameters it needs.

Anyone can give me an example of how to use it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it the API or the concept that troubles you? To put it another way, do you understand the command-line version: `svn import`? (If the concept is the problem, have you read [this page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.import)?)

Comment: Yes, I understand what the subversion command does. Anyway, thank you for the link, it may help me in the future.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to use the function. I mean: I try to use it with the parameters I think it needs, but it gives errors. If I give it just the parameters I am sure what they mean, like the path, the subversion repository and the log message, it also does not work. 
I am asking for an example, because I have not found a using example as the ones existing for other commands in this page: [link](http://pysvn.stage.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_guide.html)

Comment: Please post a short, complete program in which you "try to use it" but "it gives you errors." Please post the expected and actual results you see, including the full text of any errors. For more information about asking questions and providing good examples, see [ask] and [mcve] in the [help].

Comment: http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_import_ should have explained how to call the function. What is missing from the docs? Also each pysvn kit install an example svn_cmd.py that duplicates almost all the svn commands including import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone can give me an example of how to use it?

The following program demonstrates the use of `client.import_()`. This program performs exactly the same function as the command line:

```
svn import /tmp/example svn+ssh://t420/svnroot/trunk/example -m "Initial checkin"
```

Example program (x.py):

```
import pysvn
client = pysvn.Client()
client.import_(path='/tmp/example',
               url=u'svn+ssh://t420/svnroot/trunk/example',
               log_message='Initial checkin')
```

Result:

```
$ ls /tmp/example
hello.py  hello.txt
$ python x.py 
$ svn ls svn+ssh://t420/svnroot/trunk/example
hello.py
hello.txt
```

Comment: Thank you Rob. That was very kind of you.
Now I am calling the function like: 
`coderevision = client.import_(path='instrucciones.txt', url='http://mysvnrepository', log_message="First attempt")`
and the error it gives is:
`
python: /build/subversion-0NcZK7/subversion-1.8.8/subversion/libsvn_subr/path.c:119: svn_path_join_internal: Assertion `svn_path_is_canonical_internal(base, pool)' failed.
Abortado (``core' generado)`
I tried to use directly the svn import command, because I thought the error was related with the svn software, but it worked perfectly.

Comment: You should not see the assert errors. You could raise a bug against pysvn at http://pysvn.tigris.org for that. The reason I suspect is that your URL is not valid from SVN's point of view. Is the svn repo realy at the top of the web server?